# Migrating to Tensorflow 2.x from 1.x results in much slower training and ResourceExhaustedErrors on Google AI platform

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, google-ai-platform

Everything was working fine on Tensorflow 1.14. I now have to update it for various reasons and seemingly the training (that I do as Google AI platform jobs) has dramatically degraded: I now get `ResourceExhaustedError` for my models and even when I reduce the batch size by a bunch to get around this (which I'd rather not do anyway) the training slows down by a factor of about 5.

My migration can be summarized as my config yaml has changing from:

```
trainingInput:
  scaleTier: CUSTOM
  masterType: standard_gpu
  runtimeVersion: "1.14"
```

to

```
trainingInput:
  scaleTier: CUSTOM
  masterType: standard_gpu
  runtimeVersion: "2.5"
  pythonVersion: "3.7"
```

and updated all the relevant code to be TF2.x compliant as well obviously. I also tried fiddling with the `scaleTier` and `masterType` to no avail.

My models are Keras-based, involve LSTM and have about 2 million and 5.5 million parameters.

What can I do here? Why this extreme degredation in training quality on google AI platform when I make this change?

Comment: Are you sure you have followed all steps from [migration instruction](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate)?

Comment: @vitooh I didn't go through that with a fine tooth comb but it looks mostly not relevant for me. I am largely using keras (`tf.keras` now) in a fairly standard way so according to that document I shouldn't need to change much. The training itself is just a simple `model.fit` call with a keras model. But thanks for the link, I will continue to look at it; so far though nothing helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the problem was that I was using `recurrent_dropout` in my LSTM model, which seemingly is no longer supported for GPU training in Tensorflow 2.x. After removing that argument from my LSTM layers, the issue disappeared.

Notably, neither the [migration instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate) nor the [tf_upgrade_v2](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/upgrade) script helped with this at all.